# How to define circular boundaries in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am working with MATLAB code and I would like to define boundary conditions.
I have lightning latitude data stored in column 3 and longitude data stored in column 4.
Moreover I have a tropical cyclone eye coordinate.
Now I have 3 regions which I need to separate, namely:

1. eyewall (0 - 60 km)
2. inner rainband (60-180 km) and,
3. outer rainband (180 - 500 km). from the eye of the cyclone.

I have converted the distances in terms of degrees latitude to make it easier to deal with.
What I would like to do is count the lightning occurrences separately in these 3 regions of the cyclone the instant the eye is at a given latitude and longitude. The time is stored in the 2nd column.
I have tried to use the mathematical equivalent of a circle with center (a,b), corresponding to the center of the cyclone and r as distance from center:
(x-a)<sup>2</sup> + (y-b)<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>, with x representing the longitude column 4 and y representing the latitude column 3.
I have come up with the follow code for a particular case but it does not seem to work or compile:

```
M = A20121228;
lat = -10.6;
lon = 161.5;
hr = 0;

if  ((M(:, 4) - lon)^2 + (M(:, 3) - lat)^2) <= 0.541^2
row_idx1 = (hr == M(:, 2) & lat == M(:, 3) & lon == M(:, 4));
filtered_M1 = M(row_idx1, :);
eyewall = filtered_M1;
end      

if  ((M(:, 4) - lon)^2 + (M(:, 3) - lat)^2) > 0.541^2 && ((M(:, 4) - lon)^2 + (M(:, 3) - lat)^2) <= 1.622^2
row_idx2 = (hr == M(:, 2) & lat == M(:, 3) & lon == M(:, 4));
filtered_M2 = M(row_idx2, :);
inner = filtered_M2;
end

if  ((M(:, 4) - lon)^2 + (M(:, 3) - lat)^2) > 1.622^2 && ((M(:, 4) - lon)^2 + (M(:, 3) - lat)^2) <= 4.505^2
row_idx3 = (hr == M(:, 2) & lat == M(:, 3) & lon == M(:, 4));
filtered_M3 = M(row_idx3, :);
outer = filtered_M3;
end
```

Comment: Would you like to clarify: do you want boundary coordinates or boundary conditions? Second, you simplify to much. You need first to define the boundaries in UTM coordinates. Then map them to latitude and longitude. Otherwise you may get an error in kilometers. Do you have a license to [mapping toolbox](http://se.mathworks.com/products/mapping/?refresh=true)? Otherwise equations to use is found in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system). However, note that your problem may be a bit trickier since you may be in many utm zones at the same time.

Comment: It would help if you could post sample image and data. Could you update your post, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should form your geodetic data in terms of 'kilometer' instead of converting the ranges (0, 60, 180, 500) in terms of degrees, because working on 'kilometer' of unit is more convenient in your case. You can use [`geodetic2ned()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/geodetic2ned.html) function to convert your geodetic data to local cartesian NED (Nort - East - Down -> they are the axis of [Navigation Frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_east_down)). While using `geodetic2ned()` if you enter your `lat = -10.6` and `lon = 161.5` (I named them `lat0` and `lon0`)as an argument for reference, they will be the origin of Navigation Frame. Therefore, `N`, `E` (are the outputs of the `geodetic2ned()` function, check the code below) will be valued wrt your `lat` and `lon` (in other words `lat0` and `lon0`). By this way, you can write directly `sqrt( N.^2 + E.^2 )` instead of `sqrt( M(:, 4) - lon)^2 + (M(:, 3) - lat)^2 )` (btw you should use [Element-Wise Power](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html))

Now check the code below:

```
SPHEROID   = referenceEllipsoid('wgs84', 'km');  % // SPHEROID Reference
hr         = 0; 
lat0       = -10.6;
lon0       = 161.5;
[N, E, D]  = geodetic2ned(M(:, 3), M(:, 4), -M(:, 2), lat0, lon0, hr, SPHEROID);
range      = sqrt( N.^2 + E.^2 ); 
indEyewall = find( hr == D & range >= 0 & range < 60);
indInner   = find( hr == D & range >= 60 & range < 180);
indOuter   = find( hr == D & range >= 180 & range < 500);
eyewall    = M(indEyewall, :);
inner      = M(indInner, :);
outer      = M(indOuter, :);
```

The point, I include `hr == D` part to `find()` function because you write it in your code but I' m not sure if including it. You may get logical false from `find()` functions so if I were you, I would make sure about including it.

I hope that would be useful. Good luck..

Comment: Nice code snippet! This requires mapping toolbox of course, but working with geographical information: mapping toolbox is certainly helping :) +1

Comment: @patrik,  Thank you. Mapping toolbox is indispensable to make it simple. May you add your approach for knowledge?

Comment: Actually I was thinking of using `minvtran`, but it seems your suggestion is simpler.